# flutter doctor no muestra salida y abre otra ventana

Tags: flutter, windows10

he estado teniendo problemas instalando flutter desde 0 en mi Pc con **windows 10**

he seguido los pasos de instalacion en la documentacion oficial (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) una vez instalado al ejecutar el comando `flutter` o `flutter doctor` en un CMD arroja la salida normal.

el problema esta al momento en que se cierra la sesion o se reinicia el equipo y quiero ejecutar nuevamente esos comandos, al principio muestra una ventana con lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego de eso la ventana se cierra y no se ejecuta nada mas.

no me permite ni ejecutar ninguna app, ni correr ningun comando de flutter o dart.

### Cosas que he intentado

1. borrar la carpeta **cache** que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta **flutter** (funciona a medias ya que ocurre lo mismo, funciona al principio pero si se cierra sesion o se reinicia aparece la misma ventana al ejecutar los comandos)
2. reinstalar en diferentes directorios (C:src/flutter, C:flutter, C:Usuarios/user/flutter)
3. instalar con chocolatey (mismo problema al reiniciar o cerrar sesion)
   en todas y cada una de esas soluciones se modifico respectivamente las variables de entorno.

espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si tienes Flutter en las variables de Entorno.

1. En la barra de búsqueda escribe: **Editar las variables de entorno del sistema**.
2. Da click en **Variables de entorno**.
3. En **Variables del sistema** selecciona la variable **Path** y luego click en **Editar**.
4. Da click en **Nueva** y pega la ruta de la carpeta bin de Flutter:
   **C:\flutter\bin** (la ruta cambiará dependiendo donde hayas instalado Flutter)

Por ultimo, aceptas todas las ventanas, abres la consola y ya tendria que ejecutarte el comando flutter doctor.

Comment: Bievenido a stackoverflow! Para ayudarte a mejorar quiero comentarte que la respuesta no aporta suficiente valor o está basada en opiniones. Ten en cuenta que una respuesta debe de estar analizada, investigada y probada, y no tanto una suposición o respuesta "rápida", por favor, considera leer [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Para "investigar" la pregunta es mejor utilizar los comentarios o incluso el chat! Saludos

Comment: en realidad ya hice eso de diversas maneras pero ninguna me dio solucion,gracias igual